# How to delete a repository on VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I mistakenly opened my system's local disk as a repository while setting up vscode as my git editor. I have over 5k changes on my scm. how do you suggest I delete the repository  without losing all my system files? Mind you, the local disk repository is not showing on my git account..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete the `.git` folder if that's what you mean.

Comment: I've been able to solve the problem thanks. I found it under hidden folders in my local disk. this was mighty helpful.

Comment: but the settings are stikll in VSCode. I think the OP want to know howto how to remove the repository from VSCode